# JSON saving duplicate info

Tags: python, json

I want use Python to update JSON data.

```
import json
with open('./gui-config.json','r+') as f:
    js=json.load(f)
    js['configs'][0]['password']='123'
    f.seek(0)
    json.dump(js,f)
```

This is my test JSON named "gui-config.json":

```
{
"configs" : [
  {
"server" : "US.SSSERVER.PW",
"server_port" : 8989,
"password" : "73221446",
"method" : "aes-256-cfb",
"remarks" : ""}

],
"index" : 0,
"global" : false,
"enabled" : true,
"shareOverLan" : false,
"isDefault" : false,
"localPort" : 1080}
```

End run,the "gui-config.json" is:

```
{
  "localPort": 1080,
  "isDefault": false,
  "configs": [
    {
      "server_port": 8989,
      "method": "aes-256-cfb",
      "remarks": "",
      "password": "123",
      "server": "US.SSSERVER.PW"
    }
  ],
  "global": false,
  "enabled": true,
  "index": 0,
  "shareOverLan": false
 }
   sDefault": false,
   "localPort" : 1080
 }
```

The `"sDefault" : false, "localPort" : 1080}` is repeat info. Why did that happen?
Can I finish this operation in once open?

Comment: Why not close the file and open it again to write?
By seeking to 0 and dumping, I don't think the "entire" file is overwritten. It'll only start writing from that position but as soon as the content in the variable "js" runs out, the rest of the file will remain as it is.

Comment: "Python save JSON data wrong." Your debugging will get a whole lot better when you start looking for normal problems instead of immediately blaming the language and platform you're using. Do you honestly think a stable version of Python would have completely broken JSON support and none of us would notice and the devs wouldn't fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
with open('./gui-config.json','r') as f:
    js=json.load(f)
    js['configs'][0]['password']='123'

with open('./gui-config.json','w') as f:
    js.dumps(js, f)
```

I think that's a neater and easier to follow approach. Opening the file again to it to write clears the existing content (which you don't have to worry about as you already have a copy of it in the memory).

Comment: You don't need to open the file as `r+` the first time round. It could just be regular readable mode.

Comment: Made the change. Thank you :)